# Spring Roo example on main page does not work

Tags: java, spring-roo

I installed Spring Roo. But when I try the script at the bottom of the [Roo's main page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/), `project setup --topLevelPackage com.foo`I have this error:

> You cannot specify option 'topLevelPackage' when you have also specified '' in the same command

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Using Roo 2.0.0.RC2 everything is fine. I was using a previous version.